# How to force decision tree to split into different classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm doing a decision tree, and I would like to force the algorithm to split the results into different classes after one node. 
The problem is that in the trees that I get, after evaluating the condition (is X < than a certain value), I get two results of the same class (yes and yes, for example). I want to have "yes" and "no" as results for the evaluation of the node.
Here is the example of what I'm getting:

[image: 1]

This is the code generating the tree and the plot:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2)
clf = clf.fit(users_data, users_target)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, 
                     feature_names= feature_names,  
                     class_names= target_names,  
                     filled=True, rounded=True,  
                     special_characters=True) 

graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)  
graph
```

I expect to find "YES" and "NO" classes after the nodes. Now, I'm getting the same classes in the lasts levels after the respective conditions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As is, you model indeed does look like it doesn't offer any further discrimination between the first and the second level nodes; so, if you are *certain* that this is (kind of) optimal for your case, you can simply ask it to stop there using `max_depth=1` instead of 2:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)
```

Keep in mind however that in reality this can be far from optimal; have a look at the tree for the iris dataset from the scikit-learn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification):

[image]

where you can see that, further down the tree levels, nodes with `class=versicolor` emerge from what look like "pure" nodes of `class=virginica` (and vice versa).

So, before deciding to prune the tree beforehand to `max_depth=1`, you might want to check if leaving it to grow further (i.e. by not specifying the `max_depth` argument, thus leaving it in its [default value](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) of `None`), might be better for your case.

Everything depends on *why exactly* you are doing this (i.e. your *business* case): if it is an exploratory one, you might very well stop with `max_depth=1`; if it is a predictive one, you should consider which configuration maximizes an appropriate metric (most probably here, the accuracy).

Answer (score 0):

Try using criterion = "entropy". I find this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

The splits of a decision tree are somewhat speculative, and they happen as long as the chosen criterion is decreased by the split. This, as you noticed, does not guarantee a particular split to result in different classes being the majority after the split. Limiting the depth of the tree is part of the reason you see a split not "played out" until it can reach nodes of distinct classes.

*Pruning* the tree should help. I was able to avoid a similar problem using a suitable value of the `ccp_alpha` parameter of the `DecisionTreeClassifier`. Here are my before- and after- trees.

[image: Before pruning]

[image: After pruning]